# When to use Page.IsValid?

Tags: asp.net

I'm going through my colleagues code, he has written several `Page.IsValid` checks but I can't find a single validation control on the pages.

Is it true that without any validation controls, the `Page.IsValid` will always be true? And hence, it’s practically useless checking `Page.IsValid`, isn't it?? please advice me with some info on this

Comment: He could be future-proofing it... I wouldn't do this, but could understand the reason for it.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this, but could he be using data annotations??  I'm not sure if they need the validation controls or not.  You might also want to check to make sure he didn't roll his validation controls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `Page.IsValid`, first invoke `Page.Validate()`, which sets `Page.IsValid` to either true or false based on the validity of all validation server controls in the `Page.Validators` collection.

If you access `Page.IsValid` before invoking `Page.Validate` it may not contain a correct value.

MSDN Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.isvalid(v=vs.71).aspx